# Azure DevOps Universal Packages - Get Version of artifact downloaded from an external feed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

I'm looking a way to get the version number from an artifact downloaded with the Universal Package task from an external feed. Because I've set to download the latest version with `versionDownloadExternal : '*'` after download I need to know what version was downloaded.

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Universal download'
  inputs:
  feedsToUse: external
  externalFeedCredentials: '${{ parameters.externalFeedCredentials }}'
  feedDownloadExternal: 'temp-feed'
  packageDownloadExternal: 'temp-artifact'
  downloadDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'
  versionDownloadExternal: '*'
```

Looking at the logs of the Universal Download task I see that the version is there (1.5.0), but couldn't find a way to save this to a variable in order to use it further.

```
{"Version":"1.5.0","SuperRootId":"6AAB600ECBE6DF7FAD87B8C49E7B21E32BB1439F410F0A76E41A220630D0847002","ManifestId":"629C9E66D4A57250DD4A430723E6B9338F995133BCFE65D6868BF7E97F1723DA02","Description":"Klevr Portal Build Artifact"}
{"@t":"2021-10-27T09:18:14.3239876Z","@m":"ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session abc855f4-be5a-4de2-91ed-d9827170d1ee","@i":"889d9dc4","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackDownloadCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2021-10-27 09:18:14.323Z"}
{"@t":"2021-10-27T09:18:14.9356386Z","@m":"Found matching version: 1.5.0","@i":"2843490c","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackDownloadCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2021-10-27 09:18:14.935Z"}
{"@t":"2021-10-27T09:18:14.9902407Z","@m":"Obtained package metadata","@i":"ae648446","SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.UPackDownloadCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2021-10-27 09:18:14.990Z"}
...
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Universal Packages task does not have output variables, I am afraid that there is no way to directly generate variables related to the latest version and use them in the next task.

For a workaround, you can try to add a PowerShell task to run the Rest API: [Artifact Details - Get Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-package?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to get the latest version. Then you can set it in the pipeline variable.

Here is an example:

```
$connectionToken="PAT Token"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$url = 'https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{Feedname}/Packages/{PackageID}/versions?api-version=6.0-preview.1'

$PackageInfo = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}) 

$LatestVersion= $PackageInfo.value.version | Select-Object -first 1


Write-Host "Latest package Version = $LatestVersion"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=latestversion;isOutput=true]$LatestVersion"
```

Result:

[image]